# Shifting User Controls in .ASPX Markup

Tags: asp.net, html

A question from a non-web-designer about the preferred - and least browser-sensitive - way of shifting users controls a few pixels horizontally and vertically if I'm using divs instead of table cells.

If you look at this top part of a web page, you will notice that the lower menu is a couple of pixels too far to the left and a couple pixels too high.  (Note right edge doesn't line up with the menu above it.  Also, tops of image buttons to the right of the lower control are clipped.)

Can I position them absolutely, or use white space to shift the lower one into alignment?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Here is the approximate markup:

```
<body id="bodyTag" runat="server">
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="divAll" runat="server" style="visibility:visible;">
            <div id="divPrintHeaders" style="visibility:hidden; width: 923px;height:70px;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="printCompanyLogoImageButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/TopNav/MainLogoImage.gif" 
                    runat="server"></asp:ImageButton>
                <asp:Image ID="printPageTitleImage" ImageUrl="~/Images/PageTitle/Product_Title.gif" runat="server"></asp:Image>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="divMainHeaders" style="z-index:10;">
                <ZZ:TopNavCtrl ID="topNavCtrl" runat="server"/>
                <div style="margin-top:-13px;margin-left:-4px;height:31px;z-index : 25;">
                    <ZZ:MyMenuControl ID="myMenu" runat="server" OnMyMenu="myMain_DoStuff" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="LEFT: 12px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 120px">
                <ZZ:SomeControl id="something" runat="server"></ZZ:SomeControl>
                <!-- Several more controls here ... -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                    style=" background-color: #ffffff; LEFT: 0px; POSITION: relative; TOP: 100px; width: 740px; height: 50px;">
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder id="footerPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS use `margin-left:` (which can take a positive or negative value, usually in pixels)

```
margin-left:-5px;
```

When building menus and the such, it's easier to use [styled, unordered lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: Right, but this only works for BLOCK elements (such as DIVs), but not on INLINE elements (such as SPAN or INPUT).

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks, Diodeus.